# Android: How to load an image from gallery into the OpenCv Mat variable?

Tags: android, image, image-processing, opencv

I'm currently try to run some opencv filters (i.e find egde, Median, ...) on images which are stored in the image gallery folder.

But I get error for loading image.  My device is galaxy tab 10.1 with android 3.2, my opencv - API level 8.

I have the following source on a Button:

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

      Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/image1.jpg");                 
      Bitmap myBitmap32 = myBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
      Mat pic1 = Utils.bitmapToMat(myBitmap32);

    }
```

Here is LogCat:

```
02-07 12:31:27.290: I/System.out(16522): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
02-07 12:31:27.290: I/System.out(16522): buffer returned 
02-07 12:31:27.310: D/dalvikvm(16522): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 21% free 6975K/8775K, paused 19ms
02-07 12:31:27.320: I/dalvikvm-heap(16522): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.918MB for 6291472-byte allocation
02-07 12:31:27.340: D/dalvikvm(16522): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 13% free 13119K/14983K, paused 19ms
02-07 12:31:27.380: D/dalvikvm(16522): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 13% free 13119K/14983K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-07 12:31:27.710: D/dalvikvm(16522): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 55K, 13% free 13063K/14983K, paused 20ms
02-07 12:31:27.730: I/dalvikvm-heap(16522): Grow heap (frag case) to 24.864MB for 12582928-byte allocation
02-07 12:31:27.780: D/dalvikvm(16522): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 25351K/27335K, paused 21ms
02-07 12:31:27.830: D/dalvikvm(16522): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 8% free 25351K/27335K, paused 2ms+3ms
02-07 12:31:27.890: W/dalvikvm(16522): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lorg/opencv/android/Utils;
02-07 12:31:27.890: D/AndroidRuntime(16522): Shutting down VM
02-07 12:31:27.890: W/dalvikvm(16522): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400fc760)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at photo.klu.PhotoKLUActivity$1.onClick(PhotoKLUActivity.java:82)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3127)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:12025)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:425)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    at org.opencv.android.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:86)
02-07 12:31:27.890: E/AndroidRuntime(16522):    ... 12 more
02-07 12:31:30.010: I/dalvikvm(16522): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
02-07 12:31:30.010: I/dalvikvm(16522): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-07 12:31:37.470: I/Process(16522): Sending signal. PID: 16522 SIG: 9
```

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The openCV library is not attached to your application. Please do the following (i assume that the openCV library is imported to your workspace). On Package Explorer > Right click on the application project > properties > under Library click Add > select openCV Be sure that on Java Build Path you don't have anything related to openCV